# Create list of class from list of numbers using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers:

```
List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 5, 6, 18, 28, 40, 62 };
```

And the following class:

```
public class Measure {
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public Int32 Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a list of Measure where:

1. Each Measure Value is one of the values listed;
2. Each Measure Created is a day starting in DateTime.Now and incremented by one day.

So the list of Measure would be something like:

```
DateTime.Now, 1
DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 2
DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 5
...
```

Is it possible to create this list using Linq?

Comment: `numbers.Select((x, i) => new Measure { Value = x, Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i) })`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [Select((value, index) => ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) construction:

```
 List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 5, 6, 18, 28, 40, 62 };

 List<Measure> result = numbers
   .Select((value, index) => new Measure() {
      Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
      Value = value
     })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 5, 6, 18, 28, 40, 62 };
int dayCounter = 0;
var measureList = numbers.Select(
    x => new Measure
    {
        Value = x,
        Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dayCounter++)
    }).ToList();
```